# Debian Buster on RPi3B - Stuck after Login Screen

Tags: debian, gui, desktop

I am using Raspberry Pi 3B (1GB) model with 16GB SD Card. I installed Debian Buster 10 (20210210_raspi_3_buster.img.xz - 64-bit) and it boots correctly to command prompt. Then I `apt upgrade`d, `apt-update`d, and `apt install`ed task-cinnamon-desktop (another time, I `tasksel`ed and selected Cinnamon and Gnome too).
I tried two things, but both are a problem:

1. After the GUI install, on booting, it shows login screen, but after I fill in correct credentials, it just gets stuck and does not proceed.
2. I did Ctrl+Alt+F1 which opened a command prompt, and did startx. This time it displayed the Desktop, however there was a message "Cinnamon could not find hardware video accelerator and is using software", and I saw the 4 CPU threads running over 90%!
   I don't know if both issues are related.

I tried to look into /var/log/lightdm/lighdm.log, didn't find anything problematic. I generally looked at the syslog, same there. Another post with same problem, though about Rasbian, talks about `chown`ing /home/pi, which I don't have since its a Debian.

Where should I be looking?

Comment: why would you need to use (unstable) 64bit buster on a 1GB pi? try the stable 32bit - also,use Raspberry Pi OS - it's based on Debian, and works better on the pi - becaus eit's made for it

Comment: Is there any reason you are using a (64bit) OS - with only 1GB of memory there is actually no point! You are also making things difficult for yourself by using generic Buster rather than the Pi customised OS.

Comment: I recently started on Debian on my x64/amd64 machines, and I wanted the same OS for my RPi too. BTW, I picked up the 64-bit OS because it was listed under tested images for RPI3B+ (though mine is a 3B), no other reason. I am learning, so I wanted to go through the journey of facing issues and asking questions, which would give me a much better insight on how things works. RPi OS felt too easy, and Debian seemed to have [tested images](https://raspi.debian.net/tested-images/). I understand I would be better off with RPi OS, but I'd appreciate it if I got some direction for Debian.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue